# Register between 2 tables doesn't appear

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have two tables

```
create table TREBALLADORS(
    DNI varchar(45) primary key not null,
    Codics int not null,
    Llinatges varchar(45) not null,
    Nom varchar(45) not null,
    Data_Naixement date,
    SS varchar(45),
    Direccio varchar(120),
    CP int,
    Poblacio varchar(45),
    Telefon_casa varchar(45),
    Telefon_movil varchar(45),
    Rango varchar(45),
    Antiguitat_reconeguda date,
    N_Personal int,
    email varchar(45),
)
ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=latin1;

create table ESPECIALITATS (
    ID int primary key not null auto_increment,
    Nom varchar(60) not null,
    DNI_Treballadors_Esp varchar(45) not null ,
    Data_inici date,
    Data_fi date,
    FOREIGN KEY(DNI_Treballadors_Esp) REFERENCES TREBALLADORS(DNI)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=latin1;
```

The table "TREBALLADORS" has 209 employers registered and the table "ESPECIALITATS" only have two of these 209.

If i use the next query RETURN ALL 209. The 207 with column "especialitat" in white and the orthers 2 with his ·especialitat".

```
SELECT  tr.DNI, tr.Codics, tr.Nom, tr.Llinatges, tr.Data_Naixement, tr.SS, tr.Direccio, tr.CP,
tr.Poblacio, tr.Telefon_casa, tr.Telefon_movil, tr.Rango, tr.Antiguitat_reconeguda, tr.N_personal,
tr.email, esp.Nom as especialitat
FROM
 TREBALLADORS as tr
 left JOIN ESPECIALITATS as esp ON esp.DNI_Treballadors_Esp=tr.DNI;
```

With the next query, I only want show a employer using "LIKE". But only appear the employers registered in "especialitats".

```
SELECT tr.DNI, tr.Codics, tr.Nom, tr.Llinatges, tr.Data_Naixement, tr.SS, tr.Direccio, tr.CP, tr.Poblacio, tr.Telefon_casa, tr.Telefon_movil, tr.Rango, tr.Antiguitat_reconeguda, tr.N_personal, tr.email, esp.Nom AS especialitat
FROM TREBALLADORS AS tr
INNER JOIN ESPECIALITATS AS esp ON esp.DNI_Treballadors_Esp = tr.DNI
AND tr.DNI LIKE  '05.203-Y'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

In my case the employer "05.203-Y" or the employer "05.203-Z" (only two registered of 209) appear with the next query, but the orthers employers (05.203-D, 05.203-E, etc..) don't appear because the 207 employers are not registered in "ESPECIALITAT" but, i want show the employer with the column "ESPECIALITAT" in white although he is not registered

what's wrong?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` just like the first query.

Comment: Ok i solved using left join and change "AND" for "WHERE".

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` without any wildcard characters? That makes it the same as `=`.

Comment: = is for integers? Like is for characters?

Comment: No, `=` is for exact match of any datatype, `LIKE` is for pattern match of strings.

Comment: Ok ty for your support.